# How would you integrate $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How would you integrate $$\int_{0}^1 \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx?$$

I'm trying to see whether this diverges or converges by the way. Any help in that way would be great!

Comment: Try Taylor series maybe?

Comment: What methods do you know? Is this for a Calculus class or some sort of real analysis with Lebesgue integration?

Comment: Somewhere in between it's an "advanced calculus" class, no knowledge of lebesgue integration

Comment: @math31 Do you know of the trigonometric integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can express this integral in terms of elementary functions. Otherwise you would have found a way to express the sin integral in terms of elementary functions.

We have:

$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}
$$

We can integrate by parts. Let $u = 1-\cos x$ and $v'=\frac{1}{x^2}$ giving $u' = \sin x$ and $v = \frac{-1}{x}$.

Thus we have:

$$
\begin{align} 
\int_{0}^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} &=  \left .\frac{\cos x-1}{x}\ \right \rvert_{0}^1 + \int_{0}^1\frac{\sin x}{x} \\
\end{align}
$$

This leaves us with finding the integral of $\sin x \over x$. This is a known non-elementary function called (creatively) the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), $\text{Si}(x)$, and is defined as:

$$
\text{Si}(x) = \int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt
$$

Thus we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} &= \left .\frac{\cos x-1}{x}\right \rvert_{0}^1 + \text{Si}(1) \\
&= \cos(1) - 1 + \text{Si}(1) \\
&\approx 0.486385
\end{align}
$$

Note: the left term can be evaluated at $x=0$ by taking limits of the term to 0.

I got the value of $\text{Si}(1)$ using the taylor expansion. Alternatively you could have started with the taylor expansion of the original equation but it would have inadvertently led you to the taylor expansion of $\text{Si}(1)$ in some form.

Comment: Neither $\int_0^1 \frac1{x^2}\,dx$ nor $\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx$ converges.  Your development is flawed.  Simply integrate by parts with $u=1-\cos(x)$ and $v=1/x$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Damn you're right. It's been a while since I've done continuous mathematics it seems. I'll fix the edits. I actually got to the answer via original taylor series but thought this would be nicer as an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** remark that $\cos x \leq 1$, so your integrand is non-negative. Also, remark that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = 1/2$

Comment: I couldn't get it sorry, I'm looking for the integrand see, not the limit, how can the limit being finite would imply that this integrand converges?

Comment: @math31 The integral is convergent because you are integrating finite values over a finite range. $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = 1/2$ implies that no portion of your integral is dealing with infinite values.

Comment: Why would the integral diverge if it is finite everywhere?

Comment: @math31 write the integral as $\int_0^\varepsilon + \int_\varepsilon^1$. The right integral is finite since the integrand is continuous over a closed and bounded region. The left integral is finite since the integrand "looks like" 1/2 in the region $[0,\varepsilon]$. Not sure how much real analysis you've had but you can formalize this to whatever extent you want.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{x^2}{4!}+\frac{x^4}{6!}-\ldots \tag{1}$$
hence by termwise integration:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3\cdot 4!}+\frac{1}{5\cdot 6!}-\ldots = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)\cdot (2k+2)!} \tag{2}$$
where the last series converges very fast and with alternating signs. You just need to take four or five terms to get an extremely accurate approximation of the given, non-elementary integral, equal to $-1+\cos(1)+\text{Si}(1)$ by integration by parts.

You may also use the Laplace transform to state:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-1+\cos(1)\right)+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(1)+s\sin(1)}{(1+s^2)\,e^s}\,ds.\tag{3} $$

Answer (score 1):

As per Dr. MV's suggestion, integrate by parts
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}} dx &= \lim_{a \to 0} \int\limits_{a}^{1} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}} dx \\
&= \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x}\Big|_{a}^{1} + \int\limits_{a}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \\
&= \cos(1) - 1 - \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\cos a - 1}{a} + \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \\
&= \cos(1) - 1 + \mathrm{Si}(1)
\end{align}